# Euler #2 Fibonacci Javascript function will only return zero after crunching the numbers

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I wrote a function to solve Euler #2 in Javascript for adding all the even Fibonacci numbers up to 4,000,000. However, when I run my function, the chrome dev tool keeps giving me zero as the answer. I am not sure why.

```
function DoEverything() {
  oldnum = 0;
  num = 1;
  total = 0;
  result = addFibNumbers(num, oldnum);
  console.log(result);
} 
function addFibNumbers(num, oldnum) {
  while(num < 4000000) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      newnum = num + oldnum;
      total += newnum;
      oldnum = num;
      num = newnum;
    }
  return total;
  }
}
DoEverything();
```

Comment: You may wish to use a smaller numbers when debugging so you can easily check how it's working by logging iterations, i.e. if you logged `num` at the beginning of your `while` you could (safely) notice that the `while` only happens _once_

Comment: You can also do some analysis to find that exactly every third number is even. Thus you can do three iteration steps inside the loop and avoid the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason its returning 0:

```
result = addFibNumbers(num, oldnum);//num=1,oldNum=0

//function
while(num < 4000000) { //num is 1, so it enters while
if (num % 2 == 0) {// 1 % 2 == 1, so skip this if
return total;// this ends the function, returning total=0 as nothing was changed
```

I guess you are looking to do this:

```
  while(num < 4000000) {
      newnum = num + oldnum;
      if (newnum % 2 == 0 && newnum < 4000000) {
          total += newnum;
      }
      oldnum = num;
      num = newnum;
  }
  return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is your while loop

Change this:

```
while(num < 4000000) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      newnum = num + oldnum;
      total += newnum;
      oldnum = num;
      num = newnum;
    }
  return total;
  }
```

to this:

```
while(num < 4000000) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      newnum = num + oldnum;
      total += newnum;
      oldnum = num;
      num = newnum;
    }
}
return total;
```

Your while loop is useless with a return in it and no if statement to control it's use.

Comment: This will make an endless loop

Comment: This doesn't appear to work; since `num` is initialized to 1, it will never go into the if-statement. That means `num` will never change, and you'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to modifying your while statement inside of `addFibNumbers()` like so:

```
function addFibNumbers(num, oldnum) {
  while(num < 4000000) {
    newnum = oldnum + num;
    if (oldnum % 2 == 0) {
        total += oldnum;
    }
    oldnum = num;
    num = newnum;
  }
  return total;
}
```

you will also need to initialize the first two Fibonacci terms to 1 and 2:
    `oldnum = 1;` and `num = 2;`

Comment: That is not strictly necessary, even if it is the definition in the Euler project task. The standard Fibonacci sequence starts with 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,..., so changing the start from (0,1) to (1,2) only changes if 0 is added to the sum of even sequence elements.